# How to deal with missing data with crossfilter and DC.js?

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

Let the following dataset:

```
var dataset = [
    {
        "user": "u1",
        "question1": "answer1",
        "question2": "answer2",
        ...
    },
    ...
];
```

Assume that this dataset is not complete: some users might have answered one question, but not another. Thus this dataset has some blanks where a value "questionX" does not appear.

Assume that we create for each question, the associated pie chart like this:

```
var questions = ["question1", "question2", ...];
var cf = crossfilter(dataset);

for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {

    var questionDim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d[questions[i]]});
    var questionGrp = questionDim.group().reduceCount();

    plotPieChart("#dc-" + questions[i], questionDim, questionGrp); // helper function to plot standard DC pie chart based on a dimension and group.
}
```

It seems that the group does not correctly handle the missing values, and still categorizes the missing points into the first possible category.

1. Is it a bug?
2. If not, one possible solution is to preprocess the dataset and add the missing questions with a dummy answer (for instance 'NA'). However, by doing so, the 'NA' answer will appear as a pie. Thus how can you remove this dummy pie from the displayed results?
3. is there a better way to deal with such issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's not a bug. Crossfilter dimensions must be [naturally ordered](https://github.com/square/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#dimension) or weird stuff happens.

You should define your dimensions to handle undefined values. You can do this like so:

```
var questionDim = cf.dimension(function(d) { return d[questions[i]] ? d[questions[i]] : "No answer"});
```

Then when you define your dc.js chart, you can filter out data you don't want, if you don't want the non-answers to display in your pie chart (though you probably should display them so that viewers understand the proportion of people who answered said question):

```
dc.pieChart('#pie-chart')
  .group(questionGrp)
  .data(function(group) {
     return group.all()
                 .filter(function(d) { return d.key !== "No answer"; }); 
  })
```

Comment: awesome! it's exactly what you need to do to make it works! thanks!

Comment: Note, however, that the dc.js `.data()` function [interferes with the cap functionality](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/584), so if you need capping along with this preprocessing, you might create a ["fake group"](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-filter-the-data-before-its-charted).